# Java Stream collect data from map based on value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map<long, integer>  and I want to convert it to collection of list but condition is single list can contain indexes with sum of their value less than X . How to achieved this through java streams?
Code that need to be changed to using streams is

```
int count=0;
   List<Long> values =new LinkedList<>();
    Collection<List<Long>> collection =new LinkedList<>();
   for(Map.Entry<Long,Integer> entry : maptoProcess.entrySet())
   {
       if(count+entry.getValue()<=maxNumberAllowed){
           values.add(entry.getKey());
           count+=entry.getValue();
       }
       else
       {   collection.add(values);
             count=0;
           values=new linkedList();
       }
   }
```

Ex :- Map{{1,300},{2,50},{3,100}} maxNumberAllowed :- 300
output :- list [[1],[2,3]]

Comment: Corrected this code

Comment: You are not updating count/sum value after adding in list ?

Comment: Possible bugs: 1) The value that causes count to be exceeded is ignored - should it be added to the new list? 2) count is never updated - it should it be incremented somehow, but is it a count or a sum; if a sum you should name it thus.

Comment: Please describe using plain words what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes, i need all the list possible . and it has sum. I have added an example also to describe better.

Comment: Though your code is not correct. I think it's better to use loop in this case where you have cumulative relations.

Comment: You cannot reliably do this with streams, because it depends on the encounter order which is not determinate for streams.

Comment: I guess you could implement your own collector for this (doesn't seem very simple, though), but the final solution will be much more verbose and less expressive than your actual imperative approach. Streams aren't well-suit for this kind of task (with partial sums and accumulations according to some external criteria)